# How can I actually evaluate a #+CALL statement?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have several named source blocks in an .org file. I can execute each of them by pressing `C-c C-c` when point is on (or in) them. Now I want to call them in a row. So I added some call statements:

```
#+CALL: named_function_1
#+CALL: named_function_2
```

How can I evaluate these call statements? `C-c C-c`does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add parentheses after the name of the function in order for the function to be called:

```org
#+CALL: named_function_1()
#+CALL: named_function_2()
```

See the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html#Evaluating-Code-Blocks).

Comment: Thanks, that's it! And again it's in the manual.... :-(